# Mount a folder of an external NAS twice on raspberry pi

Tags: mount

I've mounted a folder from my NAS to a folder in my pi using:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=123 //10.0.0.8/WDSync/Experiments/my_db /home/pi/wdcloud_share
```

and with:

`df -h`

it shows that it is mounted and works alright but I'd like to access another folder of my pi from
/home/pi/IOTstack/volumes

to another different also "private" folder on my NAS

using the same command and format "mount":

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=123 //10.0.0.8/WDSync/Experiments/IOTShare /home/pi/IOTShare`

but it outputs the following error:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
```

Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

why won't it let me mount for than one folder?

Comment: '"using the same command and format "mount"' - doesn't make sense because it would just mount the first share again. What exactly is the second mount command? Can you please edit add it to the question?

Comment: Yeah so how else would you link one folder from the NAS to a pi folder?

Comment: I do not have a samba installation available but from the error message I would [check the samba shares](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102924/list-samba-shares-and-current-users) and the mount points, character by character with having extra attention to upper/lower cases.

Comment: Well I think it's something with the permission to the folder IOTshare sins It was some one elses project so it could have some special setting in there... Managed to mount another folder in the pi so I guess it's not an "amount" issue.